# TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given) and TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to access the non-existed file type by http://myipaddr:50997/notExisted.html
but I am getting the following error.
Can someone explain to me?

```
    from socket import *
    serverPort = 50997

    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)         

    serverSocket.bind(("", serverPort))

    serverSocket.listen(1)

    # Server should be up and running and listening to the incoming    connections
    while True:
    print ("Ready to serve...")

        # Set up a new connection from the client
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

        try:
            # Receives the request message from the client
            message =  connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            print ("Message is: "), message

            filename = message.split()[1]
            print ("File name is: "), filename

            f = open(filename[1:])

            outputdata = f.read()
            connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n")

    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):  
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
    connectionSocket.send("\r\n")

    # Close the client connection socket
    connectionSocket.close()

except IOError:
    # Send HTTP response message for file not found
    connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n")
    connectionSocket.send("<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html>\r\n")
    # Close the client connection socket
    connectionSocket.close()

    serverSocket.close()
```

The error that I am getting.

```
connectionSocket.send(bytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n","UTF-8"))
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

I have this error when I try to remove the bytes();

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcpServer.py", line 26, in <module>
    connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n","UTF-8")
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: Just send a byte string: `connectionSocket.send(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n")`

Comment: Your title should state your actual problem, not just your objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message an integer is required is a bit confusing, since you can call `.send()` with a `bytes` argument, so you were on the right track.

However, you call `bytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n","UTF-8")`, i.e. with two arguments. You don't need to provide an encoding to the `bytes()` cast, `bytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n")` is enough.

If you want to specify an encoding, use this instead:

```
"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n".encode('UTF-8')
```

i.e.:

```
connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n".encode("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcpServer.py", line 26, in <module>
    connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n").encode("UTF-8")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: You  stuck the `.encode()` on the result of the `send()`, but you need to stick it onto the string - reread my answer.